# Which one represents null? undef or empty string

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi

I want to insert `null` in a column in a table.

**Which one represents null? `undef` or empty string `''`.**

Which one should be used and Why? I know about `defined` and that I can check it.

But I am looking more from perspective of database.

Which one represents `null` more properly?

**Update:** I am using `DBI` module.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DBI uses `undef` to represent a SQL `NULL`.  The empty string represents an empty string.

However, some *databases* don't make a distinction between `NULL` and the empty string.  [Oracle is a particular offender here.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=oracle%20null%20empty%20string)  DBI can't do anything about that.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming Perl DBI, `undef` represents a SQL `NULL`.

An empty string in Perl represents exactly the same (i.e. an empty string) in SQL.

Comment: If both of them represents `NULL`,then which one to use?

Comment: @Drt, they *don't* both represent `NULL`. `undef` does.

Comment: @Axeman and @Alnitak..When I do `select * from tablename where columnname is null`. I get same rows in each case. :(

Comment: @ Alnitak..In two cases 1. if update column with `''` 2. If update with `undef`. Same rows for `where columnname is null`

Comment: @Drt, it's also possible that your _database_ doesn't make a distinction between `NULL` and the empty string.  DBI can't do anything about that.  What database are you using?

Comment: @Drt, there's your problem.  [Oracle treats the empty string as `NULL`.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=oracle%20null%20empty%20string)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using the DBI module, and are using bound arguments (since if you were constructing the SQL by hand, you would use `NULL` in the string):

> Undefined values, or `undef`, are used to indicate NULL values.

See [the perldoc for DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values)

If you aren't using DBI directly (e.g. you are using DBIx::Class or some other ORM) then you will probably find that it inherits the behaviour of DBI for this.

Comment: So if I run `select` statement on that column, what will it return for `undef`.

Comment: Since it won't have `undef` in it, that question doesn't make sense. If it is NULL then you will get `undef` out. See the documentation I pointed you at in my answer: [undef   NULL values are represented by undefined values in Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#Notation_and_Conventions)

Comment: Be careful passing NULL to as a bound parameter. Some databases won't do what you expect and require "where x is null" and "where x = ?" and a NULL parameter is not always the same. I wrote up a summary of the discussion on dbi-users years ago at http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/dbd_odbc_tutorial_part_2.html#nulls